# Running rspec tests in vim

Tags: vim, rspec

I am very new to VIM and I'm trying to set up my system so I can run spec tests from it.

I have followed this git repo... https://github.com/thoughtbot/vim-rspec

And added all the relevant parts to the `~/.vimrc` file. But I just don't know how to actually run the tests now?

My .vimrc file now contains...

```
" RSpec.vim mappings
map <Leader>t :call RunCurrentSpecFile()<CR>
map <Leader>s :call RunNearestSpec()<CR>
map <Leader>l :call RunLastSpec()<CR>
map <Leader>a :call RunAllSpecs()<CR>
let g:rspec_runner = "os_x_iterm2"
```

but I don't know enough yet to know how to invoke this?

I have tried `:call RunCurrentSpecFile()` and it just says "Unknown function".

Comment: It sounds like `vim-rspec` is not in your `'runtimepath'` or to say another way, it sounds like you did not install `vim-spec` correctly. You can use `:scriptnames` to see which files have been sourced by Vim.

Comment: @PeterRincker I fixed this now. You were right. Thanks